# How to add subtotal button to Integrated Data Access ( ALV with IDA ) toolbar report?

Tags: abap

I want to add subtotal button to integrated data access ( ALV With IDA ) toolbar report. similar functionality we do with SALV.I have attached images as well.

[image: SALV subtotal Button]

[image: IDA Total]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button already exist, you need to complete below requirement:

1. At least one totalized column.
2. At least one sorted column.

More details are at [ZEVOLVING](http://zevolving.com/category/salv-tutorial/salv-ida/) blog [Column Settings](http://zevolving.com/2016/08/salv-ida-column-settings/) post and [SAP Learners blog post](http://www.saplearners.com/totals-and-sub-totals-in-alv-with-ida-on-hana/).

Working sample example:

```
CLASS lcl_alv DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS:
      generate_alv.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    DATA: o_salv_ida TYPE REF TO if_salv_gui_table_ida.
ENDCLASS.


START-OF-SELECTION.
  NEW lcl_alv( )->generate_alv( ).

CLASS lcl_alv IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD generate_alv.
    o_salv_ida = cl_salv_gui_table_ida=>create( iv_table_name = 'SBOOK' ).

    DATA(lo_layout) = o_salv_ida->default_layout( ).
    DATA(lt_sort_rule) = VALUE if_salv_gui_types_ida=>yt_sort_rule(
                       ( field_name = 'FLDATE'
                         descending = abap_false
                         is_grouped = abap_true ) ).
    lo_layout->set_sort_order( it_sort_order = lt_sort_rule ).

    DATA(lt_aggr_rules) = VALUE if_salv_gui_types_ida=>yt_aggregation_rule(
                       ( field_name = 'LUGGWEIGHT'
                         function   = if_salv_service_types=>cs_function_code-sum ) ).
    lo_layout->set_aggregations( lt_aggr_rules ).

    o_salv_ida->fullscreen( )->display( ).

  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: I have viewed ZEVOLVING. The examples are related to SALV. I am looking for solution of  ALV with Integrated Data Access.

Comment: Working example is great for understanding.